# how to update my like count on specific posts when button is pressed with firebase and swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a button that when you press it updates the likeCount and adds by 1. I can update the likeCount easily but I cannot make it so each post has its own like count. Well, I can, but I can't update it since the Post in is not changeable as its a let. Any ideas?? Here is my code. I would like the likeCount to be Post.likeCount, which is stored in my firebase to be updated. Currently I have a normal like count but that does not work correctly.

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestore

import Firebase
struct ContentViewHelp: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ContentView1()
    }
}
struct ContentView1: View {
    @State var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    @State var firstPress = false
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = userViewModel()
    @State var likeCount = 0
    @StateObject var settings = observableSchool()
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    @State private var colors: [Color] = [Color("color1"), Color("color2"), Color("color3"), Color("color4"), Color("color5")]
    
    var body: some View {
        let login = PostCardService()
        
        ZStack{
            NavigationView{
                ScrollView{
                    
                    
                    ForEach(viewModel.allPosts) { Post in
                        
     
                        
                        var randColor: Color = colors.randomElement()!
                        
                        if (Post.schoolCap == settings.schoolNameOD) {
                            
                            ZStack{
                                VStack{
                                    VStack{
                                        

                                        Text(Post.teachCap)
                                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 90, alignment: .leading)
                                            .font(.custom("Poppins-Bold", size: 17))
                                            .padding(15)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color("white"))
                                        HStack{
                                            Image(systemName: "graduationcap.fill")
                                                .foregroundColor(Color("white"))
                                                .frame(width: 10, height: 10, alignment: .leading)
                                                .padding(15)
                                            Text("\(settings.schoolNameOD)")
                                                .foregroundColor(Color("white"))
                                                .font(.custom("Poppins-Bold", size: 12))
                                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 90, alignment: .leading)
                                            
                                        }
                                        HStack{
                                            Image(systemName: "hand.thumbsup.fill")
                                                .foregroundColor(Color("white"))
                                                .padding(30)
                                                .onTapGesture(perform: {
                                                   likeCount += 1
                                                    PostService.AllPosts.document(Post.postId).updateData(["likes": likeCount, "\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)": true])
                                                  

//ABOVE IS WHAT I AM TALKING ABOUT. Post.likeCount is what I want to change but it won't change. Or any other way to change the likeCount of each post. 



                                                })
                                               
                                            Image(systemName: "hand.thumbsdown.fill")
                                                .foregroundColor(Color("white"))
                                                .padding(30)
                                            Image(systemName: "flag.circle.fill")
                                                .foregroundColor(Color("white"))
                                                .padding(30)
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                        }
                                    }
                                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).fill(randColor))
                                    HStack{
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                    }
                                }
                            
                            }.padding(0.2)
                            
                            
                        }
                    }.onAppear(perform:  self.viewModel.fetchData)
                }.padding(.top, 1)
                    .navigationBarTitle("most recent posts", displayMode: .automatic).foregroundColor(Color("color5"))
                
            }
        }
        
        
    }
}

struct ContentView1_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView1()
    }
}
```

Comment: Put everything inside the `ForEach` inside its own view that has an `@Binding`

Comment: @loremipsum Binding for what?

Comment: Watch [this video](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10018) what you need is right about minute 8 to make SwiftUI work.

Comment: You should also Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) there are many little tweaks your code needs and you should move everything that isn't directly related to displaying and getting stuff for the user out of the `View` and into a `ViewModel` (Firestore stuff). The `View` should not do any work. That `login` variable  will get recreated many times.